# Phonegap: launch firefox browser

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, cordova, websocket

I have developed a web app with **PhoneGap**. I use websockets and Websocket doesn't work
in android with the default browser. However, websockets works in Firefox and Chrome. So, is it possible to launch firefox or Chrome browser if I use PhoneGap?

Answer (score 1):

Just found this blogpost, some minutes ago:
http://tannerburson.com/blog/2012/05/28/IntentChooser-my-first-PhoneGap-Cordova-plugin/

It describes a plugin, that will start an intent.

Never used it, but that seems to be the correct way.

Just wondering: Wht should hppen, if neither firefox nor chrome is installed?